# Get combine validation of Switch and Currency to show correct pricing

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I am currently working on a pricing page which is getting very tricky. I am just a beginner in JS but getting through it. My task is to show the prices of a SAAS product on the pricing table. The trick is to show prices in different currencies and Annually/Quarterly. I wrote a code that takes the State of a Switch(Annually/Quarterly) and checks which Currency button is clicked. And it is working fine but it is not working in reverse. Toggling Switch does nothing because I am not getting a way to check which currency is clicked and what is the state of Switch or vice-versa at the same time. The code works fine until I interact with the switch.
I wrote the below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#usdBtn').click(function() {
    var switchh = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
    if (switchh.checked) {
      console.log("Switch is Checked");
      currMnUsd();
    } else {
      console.log("Switch is not Checked");
      currAnnUsd();
    }
  });

  $('#eurBtn').click(function() {
    var switchh2 = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
    if (switchh2.checked) {
      console.log("Switch is Checked");
      currMnEur();
    } else {
      console.log("Switch is not Checked");
      currAnnEur();
    }
  });

  $('#gbpBtn').click(function() {
    var switchh3 = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
    if (switchh3.checked) {
      console.log("Switch is Checked");
      currMnGbp();
    } else {
      console.log("Switch is not Checked");
      currAnnGbp();
    }
  });

  function currAnnUsd() {
    document.getElementById("start-price").textContent = "$20";
    document.getElementById("mid-price").textContent = "$30";
  }

  function currAnnEur() {
    document.getElementById("start-price").textContent = "Eur25";
    document.getElementById("mid-price").textContent = "Eur35";
  }

  function currAnnGbp() {
    document.getElementById("start-price").textContent = "40 GBP";
    document.getElementById("mid-price").textContent = "50 GBP";
  }

  function currMnUsd() {
    document.getElementById("start-price").textContent = "$25";
    document.getElementById("mid-price").textContent = "$40";
  }

  function currMnEur() {
    document.getElementById("start-price").textContent = "Eur30";
    document.getElementById("mid-price").textContent = "Eur40";
  }

  function currMnGbp() {
    document.getElementById("start-price").textContent = "45 GBP";
    document.getElementById("mid-price").textContent = "50 GBP";
  }
});
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input id="mycheckbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<button id="usdBtn">USD</button>
<button id="eurBtn">EUR</button>
<button id="gbpBtn">GBP</button>

<div id="start-price">$20</div>
<div id="mid-price">$30</div>
```

As I mentioned I am not a pro but I learned from StackOverflow. I tried adding eventListeners to the Switch but it is only working for one currency only.